# Writing a Bayesifier Keras wrapper

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to add Bayesian weight uncertainty to my Keras layers. After some coding I realized that Bayesifier could be implemented as a wrapper for any kind of layer, but I'm facing one issue.

A primer on bayesian weight uncertainty:

Consider an ANN layer with `m` learnable parameters. A Bayesian version of this layer with a Gaussian distribution on the weights would store another set of `m` parameters. The first `m` would be considered means, the new set of `m` would be considered variances for the weights, so every weight is characterized by a normal distribution.

In the learning phase we sample weights from this distribution. Using the reparametrization trick, we can still do backpropagation.

As you can see, converting a layer to a bayesian layer does not depend on the layer's architecture. We just duplicate the weights.

So I built a Keras wrapper class like so:

```
from keras.layers.wrappers import Wrapper
from keras import backend as K

K.set_learning_phase(1)


class Bayesify(Wrapper):

    def __init__(self, base_layer,
                 variational_initializer="ones",
                 variational_regularizer=None,
                 variational_constraint=None,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(base_layer, **kwargs)
        self.variational_initializer = variational_initializer
        self.variational_regularizer = variational_regularizer
        self.variational_constraint = variational_constraint
        self.mean = []
        self.variation = []

    def build(self, input_shape=None):
        super().build(input_shape)
        if not self.layer.built:
            self.layer.build(input_shape)
            self.layer.built = True
        self.mean = self.layer.trainable_weights[:]
        for tensor in self.mean:
            self.variation.append(self.add_weight(
                name="variation",
                shape=tensor.shape,
                initializer=self.variational_initializer,
                regularizer=self.variational_regularizer,
                constraint=self.variational_constraint
            ))
        self._trainable_weights = self.mean + self.variation

    def _sample_weights(self):
        return [mean + K.log(1. + K.exp(log_stddev))*K.random_normal(shape=mean.shape)
                for mean, log_stddev in zip(self.mean, self.variation)]

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        self.layer._trainable_weights = K.in_train_phase(self._sample_weights(), self.mean)
        return self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)
```

Short script to run a bayesian Dense layer on MNIST:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.datasets import mnist

from bayesify import Bayesify

(lX, lY), (tX, tY) = mnist.load_data()
lX, tX = lX / 255., tX / 255.
onehot = np.eye(10)
lY, tY = onehot[lY], onehot[tY]

inputs = Input(lX.shape[1:])
x = Bayesify(Dense(30, activation="tanh"))(inputs)
x = Dense(lY.shape[1], activation="softmax")(x)

ann = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
ann.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy")
ann.fit(lX, lY, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_data=(tX, tY))
```

The learning script raises weird internal Keras exceptions which I'm trying to figure out now.
Also I'm not entirely sure that the gradients of the wrapper's weights will be handled correctly.
I am currently pushing the sampled weights into the wrapped layer using the setter of the `layer.trainable_weights` property and simply forwarding `call()` to `layer.call()`.

One such error:

```
File "/data/Prog/PyCharm/bayesforge/xp_mnist.py", line 20, in <module>
    ann.fit(lX, lY, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_data=(tX, tY))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 
    1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 
    1480, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 
    113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 
    dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 10)
```

One small note, I only tested my scripts with the tensorflow backend.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how this wrapping could be accomplished?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Could you add them to the question?